# How do I update the first n columns by adding each to a defined column in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame (df) below and I want to be able to add A to test and keep it called A, then B to test and keep that called B and then C to test and again keep that called C without hard-coding the column names (I will know exactly how many columns there are to add to test and the name of test so both of those aspects can be part of the code):

```
       | A      | B      | C      | test
------ | ------ | ------ | ------ | ------
area_1 | 0.870  | 0.435  | 0.968  | 0.679
area_2 | 0.456  | 0.259  | 0.906  | 0.467
area_3 | 0.298  | 0.256  | 0.457  | 0.768
area_4 | 0.994  | 0.987  | 0.365  | 0.765
```

Currently my code look like this (n is set to the number of columns I want to add to test) but it's leaving me with loads of NAs:

```
for (j in 1:n) {
df[,j] <- eval(df[,j] + df$test)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not simply do:

```
df[, -ncol(df)] <- df[, -ncol(df)] + df[[ncol(df)]]
```

---

**Example**

```
df <- data.frame(a = rep(1,5), b = rep(2, 5), c = rep(3,5))
#  a b c
#1 1 2 3
#2 1 2 3
#3 1 2 3
#4 1 2 3
#5 1 2 3

df[, -ncol(df)] <- df[, -ncol(df)] + df[[ncol(df)]]
#  a b c
#1 4 5 3
#2 4 5 3
#3 4 5 3
#4 4 5 3
#5 4 5 3
```

Comment: Thanks @Zheyuan Li - the above works perfectly to add to all columns, I forgot to specify that I would need a way to only process this command only over the first n columns? I want to do this for the first 131 columns but there are another 131 columns after those which I want to subtract test from. Any help there would be great, again I wouldn't be able to hard-code 131.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `lapply()`:

```
df[1:3] <- lapply(df[-4], function(x) x + df$test)
> df
#           A     B     C  test
#area_1 1.549 1.114 1.647 0.679
#area_2 0.923 0.726 1.373 0.467
#area_3 1.066 1.024 1.225 0.768
#area_4 1.759 1.752 1.130 0.765
```

Comment: Thanks @mtoto - is there any way to process this command only over the first n columns? I want to do this for the first 131 columns but there are another 131 columns after those which I want to subtract test from

Comment: you can replace `df[-4]`  by `df[1:3]`, n being 3 as in your question.